# How can I test a plug that calls an action_fallback controller?

Tags: model-view-controller, elixir, phoenix-framework

Hello I am currently trying to get this test pass

```
  test "authentication plug should return 401 when not authenticated", %{conn: conn} do  
    conn = Map.put(conn, :params, %{})
    conn =  ChaacServerWeb.Plugs.Authentication.call(conn, nil)
    assert json_response(conn, 401)["errors"] != %{}
  end
```

Here is my plug

```
  def call(conn, _) do
     token = List.first(get_req_header(conn, "authorization"))
     case Accounts.validate_token(conn.params["user_id"], token) do
     {:ok, valid_token} -> conn
     err -> 
       conn 
       |> halt() 
       |> ChaacServerWeb.FallbackController.call(err)
     end
  end
```

I get this error

```
1) test authentication plug should return 401 when not authenticated (ChaacServerWeb.AuthenticationTest)                                                                               test/chaac_server_web/plugs/authentication_test.exs:26                                           
** (RuntimeError) cannot render template :"401" because conn.params["_format"] is not set. 
Please set `plug :accepts, ~w(html json ...)` in your pipeline.                          
code: conn =  ChaacServerWeb.Plugs.Authentication.call(conn, nil)                         
stacktrace:                                                                                 
 (phoenix) lib/phoenix/controller.ex:689: Phoenix.Controller.render/3                      
 test/chaac_server_web/plugs/authentication_test.exs:28: (test)
```

I understand I need to call `plug :accepts, [:json]` somehow in my test setup but how do I do that? Thanks

(EDIT) My router has `plug :accepts, [:json]` in my pipeline

Answer (score 0):

I just did

```
test "authentication plug should return 401 when not authenticated", %{conn: conn} do  
  conn = Map.put(conn, :params, %{"_format" => "json"})
  conn =  ChaacServerWeb.Plugs.Authentication.call(conn, nil)
  assert json_response(conn, 401)["errors"] != %{}
end
```

Feels abit hacky but it works for me.

Comment: This code leaves the original problem stay, hiding it under hacky test pass. This test is completely equivalent to `assert true`.

Comment: I already have this line on my router
`plug :accepts, ~w|html json|`

Comment: I think the downvote is unnecessary and I dont quite see how it is a hacky test pass. My test is to get my plug call return a 401 if I dont have a userID in :params and a token in authorization header. Now without `conn = Map.put(conn, :params, %{"_format" => "json"})` , :params is of type `Plug.Conn.Unfetched`. My plug breaks on this `conn.params["user_id"]` without that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `put_req_header`:

```
setup %{conn: conn} do
    {:ok, conn: put_req_header(conn, "accept", "application/json")}
end
```

Comment: I already have this in my setup. Its the default for api tests

Comment: Perhaps I'm wrong, but is there a need for `halt ()`? Have you tried to remove it?

Comment: if this does not help, then it's worth trying to print to log `conn` after each step, and see when it loses `_format`